# Subdomains and 1and1 hosting

Tags: hosting, subdomain

Good morning,

I've recently taken over a website for a friend and am trying to create a new subdomain on their 1and1 host to add new content.  For example, they have www.bar.com registered and pointed to their 1and1 host and it works fine.  We now want to add www.foo.bar.com that will display different content than www.bar.com.  I have spent two days muddling through the 1and1 administration trying everything I can think of to get this to work and so far, no dice.  Is there some magical step that I'm missing with 1and1 to get this to work?

In addition I tried adding a new folder so that it would instead be www.bar.com/foo and that delivers a 404 (which I find extremely frustrating as I've done that with other hosts).  Is there something magical that needs to happen with 1and1 to get that to work?

Any help/suggestions would be MUCH appreciated as I've spent two days fighting with this now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems that you are not able to find proper options of doing it in their control panel. The best way is to create a support ticket with them. They also must be having some kind of knowledgebase ( all hosting provider does ) which can help you